# android JSON parsing result NULL jsonobject

Tags: android, json, parsing

i'm trying to create a list of objects from a JSON file but my result is always NULL[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oriq5.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN5yc.png)

Comment: share the code that you tried?

Comment: is your file situated in the asset folder?

Comment: Do not post code snippets as an image (it makes it hard to provide a solution because we would have to re-type your code to get an workable model--I will never do that!). You should always provide a sample of the data you wish to parse, otherwise to much guess work on my part--I will never try to guess what the "could-be". Without providing this your question stands a large probability of NOT being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on this line

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("listBeer.json");
```

You have pass you JSON string here, not the file name. See documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)). Your code will thow JSONException, since string `listBeer.json` is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Certainly, that is the problem, but it is not a solution.